# Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 134217728 bytes. The amount of available memory may be low

Tags: .net, wcf

I am trying to save a huge data to database through a WCF service call. I am not able to invoke the service. Its throwing a error.

```
codeProxy.SaveCodes(requestHeader, codes, Rawcodes);
```

> Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 134217728 bytes. The
>   amount of available memory may be low

I have configued the web config on server and client side to max limits.

client web.config

```
<binding name="WSHttpBinding_dataService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
```

server web.config

```
<service name="ser.WSHttpBinding_dataService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
      <endpoint contract="ser.IDataservice" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="datacodeservice" />
      </service>

<wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="datacodeservice" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
          <security mode ="None">
            <!--<message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />-->
          </security>
        </binding>


<serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="100" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>

        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
```

Comment: So how much data do you want to send? Does it work for less?

Answer (score 1):

Use Stream property in message contract of WCF operation to transfer large objects.

```
[MessageContract]
public class DocumentDescription
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://example.com/App")]
    public Stream Stream { get; set; }
}
```

Configure your binding this way

```
<binding name="Binding_DocumentService" receiveTimeout="03:00:00"
        sendTimeout="02:00:00" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000">
    <security mode="Transport" />
</binding>
```

To upload large data into SQL Server database use approach described in the following article [Download and Upload images from SQL Server via ASP.Net MVC](http://rusanu.com/2010/12/28/download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server-with-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: We are passing a collection of 50 k records from presentation layer to WCF service using wshttpbinding.

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter this issue on a .Net 2.0 service this hotfix may help

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974065

> ### Issue
>
> When you are running a .NET Framework 2.0-based application, the
>   application crashes. If you debug the application, you notice that a
>   System.InsufficientMemoryException exception is thrown. Then, you
>   receive an error message that resembles the following: Failed to
>   allocate a managed memory buffer of  bytes. The amount of available
>   memory may be low.
>
> ### CAUSE
>
> Cause of Issue 1
>
> This issue occurs intermittently when the application tries to
>   allocate memory for a large object in a large object heap (LOH). The
>   error message is triggered when the following conditions are true: The
>   heap cannot provide sufficient memory to satisfy the LOH allocation
>   request. A concurrent garbage collection is in progress at the same
>   time. Cause of Issue 2
>
> This issue occurs because garbage collector heap balancing for small
>   object allocations is not performed diligently on computers that have
>   more than 8 logical processors. Because of this, more garbage
>   collections are triggered to maintain heap balancing when there is an
>   unbalanced workload in different processors. Therefore, the
>   application spends more time on garbage collection.