# Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 67108864 bytes. The amount of available memory may be low

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a problem i am using the following configuration at production machine this configuration give me this error.

"Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 67108864 bytes. The amount of available memory may be low."

but when i restore same database on my development machine and run the service with same configuration it works fine.

Binding Client Side

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ExtendedwsHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="23:59:59" textEncoding="utf-16">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"   />
      <security>
        <message establishSecurityContext="false"  />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Binding Server Side:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ExtendedConfiguration" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
      <security>
        <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security>
    </binding>
</bindings>
```

behaviour server side:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="returnFaults">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
```

but on production server it gives the error

**"The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.**"

and when i run the trace for WCF service i found out

**"Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 67108864 bytes. The amount of available memory may be low."**

can any one tell me how can i solve this problem

Regards,

ADL

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20209641/failed-to-allocate-a-managed-memory-buffer-of-134217728-bytes-the-amount-of-ava

Comment: The duplicate has no direct answers but when you want this to stay open, detail the version(s) involved and why/how you need 67MB blocks.