# streaming big file to azure over wcf failed

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I need to upload a big file to Azure storage. As a first step, I am trying to upload the file to web service folder via wcf service. I followed the steps in this link [Streaming files over WCF](http://bartwullems.blogspot.ca/2011/01/streaming-files-over-wcf.html). My service code:

```
namespace MilkboxGames.Services
{    
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IFileUploadService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        UploadResponse Upload(UploadRequest request);
    }

    [MessageContract]
    public class UploadRequest
    {
        [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
        public string BlobUrl { get; set; }

        [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
        public Stream data { get; set; }
    }

    [MessageContract]
    public class UploadResponse
    {
        [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
        public bool UploadSucceeded { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And

```
namespace MilkboxGames.Services
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]


    public class FileUploadService : IFileUploadService
    {
        #region IFileUploadService Members

        public UploadResponse Upload(UploadRequest request)
        {                                    
            try
            {                                                                                                        

                string uploadDirectory = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

                string path = Path.Combine(uploadDirectory, "zacharyxu1234567890.txt");
                if (File.Exists(path))
                {
                    File.Delete(path);
                }

                const int bufferSize = 2048;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                using (FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    int bytesRead = request.data.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    while (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        bytesRead = request.data.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    }
                    outputStream.Close();
                }

                return new UploadResponse
                {
                    UploadSucceeded = true
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new UploadResponse
                {
                    UploadSucceeded = false
                };
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="600"    
    maxRequestLength="2097152" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="FileUploadServiceBinding" messageEncoding="Mtom" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" transferMode="Streamed">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>  
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="MilkboxGames.Services.FileUploadService" behaviorConfiguration="FileUploadServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MilkboxGames.Services.IFileUploadService" bindingConfiguration="FileUploadServiceBinding">
        </endpoint>          
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="FileUploadServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

To consume this service, I created a console application and added the wcf service to Service References. I noticed that the service method becomes 'public bool Upload(string BlobUrl, System.IO.Stream data)' instead of 'public UploadResponse Upload(UploadRequest request)'. Can somebody explain to me why?

Client code:

```
        string blobUrl = "assassinscreedrevelationsandroid/GT-I9100G/assassinscreedrevelationsandroid.apk";

        string fileName = "C:\\ws_new\\XuConsoleApplication\\XuConsoleApplication\\bin\\Debug\\motutcimac.myar"; 

        bool bUploadBlobResult;

        byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

        Console.WriteLine("Size = " + buffer.Length);

        Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName);

        FileUploadServiceClient objFileUploadServiceClient = new FileUploadServiceClient();

        bUploadBlobResult = objFileUploadServiceClient.Upload(blobUrl, fileStream);
```

I managed to upload a file of 123.8MB. When I try to upload a file of 354.6MB, I got the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InsufficientMemoryException: Failed to allocate
 a managed memory buffer of 371848965 bytes. The amount of available memory   
may be low. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 
'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
    at System.Runtime.Fx.AllocateByteArray(Int32 size)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I am unable to figure out why this happened. Any help or advice are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Unhandled Exception: System.InsufficientMemoryException: Failed to
>   allocate  a managed memory buffer of 371848965 bytes. The amount of
>   available memory    may be low.

above message is indicating your app is using up all the memory that allowed, to increase the limit i think you will need a larger value on attribute "maxReceivedMessageSize"

also from another thread ([Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 134217728 bytes. The amount of available memory may be low](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20209641/failed-to-allocate-a-managed-memory-buffer-of-134217728-bytes-the-amount-of-ava)), it recommend to use stream transfer mode for large file upload.

> Use Stream property in message contract of WCF operation to transfer
>   large objects.

```
[MessageContract]
public class DocumentDescription
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://example.com/App")]
    public Stream Stream { get; set; }
}
Configure your binding this way

<binding name="Binding_DocumentService" receiveTimeout="03:00:00"
        sendTimeout="02:00:00" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000">
    <security mode="Transport" />
</binding>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It turns out that I also need to set maxReceivedMessageSize in app.config of my console app.