# WCF maxBufferSize and out of memory exceptions, related?

Tags: c#, wcf, out-of-memory

Is it possible that a large `maxBufferSize`could cause an out of memory exception? (`System.InsufficientMemoryException: Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 67108864 bytes. The amount of available memory may be low.`)?

Comment: It may be. It may be not. Why guess when you can check where/when/why memory is allocated?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Lowering your buffer size will definitely help to remove the error, but WCF doesn't allocate the memory until it needs to. So apparently you're trying to send something that needs upwards of 67mb of memory to send/receive. That being the case, lowering the buffer size is only going to cause the send/receive to fail unless you tweak something else.

If applicable for you try this solution: [wcf error while communicating large data](http://thedevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/01/wcf-error-while-communicating-large.html)

The gist of it is to try to turn on streaming mode if you can on both your client and your server endpoints.

```
...
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="your_binding" maxReceivedMessageSize="your_max"
           transferMode="Streamed"/>
</basicHttpBinding>
...
```

Also, try looking at this post: [Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 134217728 bytes. The amount of available memory may be low](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20209641/failed-to-allocate-a-managed-memory-buffer-of-134217728-bytes-the-amount-of-ava)